# Append some html text to a Yii Widget

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, widget

I have the following Yii widget and want to pass some html at the just before and just after the items are iterated through- can anyone explain how I do this?

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.zii.ListViewShowAll', array(
'summaryText' => false,
    'template' => '{items}',
    'htmlOptions' => array(),
    'itemView' => 'application.views.widgets.account.prizes._mainprizeItem',

);
```

Comment: Is this for every time you use the widget or just a single instance? If it is just a single time simply put it in your view before and after you call this widget code.

Comment: i worked out the template can pass html before and after the {items} placeholder - thanks for help still its appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just amended the widget code above...

```
'template' => '{<p>someting</p> items <p>more text</p>}',
```